# convertint date and time string to just integers in C++

Tags: c++

How to convert

std::string strdate = "2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";

To some thing like this

std::string strintdate = "20120625053206963" // basically i removed -, :, space and .

I think I should use strtok or string functions, but I am not able to do it, can any one please help me here with sampel code.

so that i convert it to unsigned __int64 by using

```
// crt_strtoui64.c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned __int64 atoui64(const char *szUnsignedInt) {
   return _strtoui64(szUnsignedInt, NULL, 10);
}

int main() {
   unsigned __int64 u = atoui64("18446744073709551615");
   printf( "u = %I64u\n", u );
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and collect the digits before converting? Or use regex in C++11

Answer (score 3):

```
bool nondigit(char c) {
    return c < '0' || c > '9';
}

std::string strdate = "2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";
strdate.erase(
    std::remove_if(strdate.begin(), strdate.end(), nondigit),
    strdate.end()
);

std::istringstream ss(strdate);
unsigned __int64 result;
if (ss >> result) {
    // success
} else {
    // handle failure
}
```

Btw, your representation as a 64-bit int might be a bit fragile. Make sure that the date/time `2012-06-25 05:32:06` is input as `2012-06-25 05:32:06.000`, otherwise the integer you get out of the end is smaller than expected (and hence might be confused for a date/time in the year 2AD).

Comment: @jrok: because it's locale-specific, and I can't remember whether `operator>>` is too. Also because `isdigit` doesn't accept negative input, so there's an extra cast needed and an extra explanation to go with it. There's the template version of `isdigit` in `<locale>`, though, which avoids the latter problem at the cost (for me, anyway) of having to look it up before using it.

Comment: An alternative would be just to remove the 5 characters that the questioner listed, not use any kind of test for a digit. That would mean there are more kinds of malformed input that fail at the end, which is a good thing or a bad thing according to whether you want to catch bad input, or just get on with it and blame whoever gave you the bad input :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11 features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("2012-06-25 05:32:06.963");
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),
                           s.end(),
                           [](const char a_c) { return !isdigit(a_c); }),
            s.end());
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use string replace to replace the unwanted chars with no chars
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
bool not_digit (int c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }

std::string date="2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";
// construct a new string
std::string intdate(date.begin(), std::remove_if(date.begin(), date.end(), not_digit));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use strtok. Here's a fairly simple method that just uses `std::string` member functions:

```
std::string strdate = "2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";
size_t pos = strdate.find_first_not_of("1234567890");
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    size_t endpos = strdate.find_first_of("1234567890", pos);
    strdate.erase(pos, endpos - pos);
    pos = strdate.find_first_not_of("1234567890");
}
```

This is not a super efficient approach, but it will work.

A perhaps more efficient approach might use a stringstream...

```
std::string strdate = "2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";

std::stringstream out;

for (auto i = strdate.begin(); i != strdate.end(); i++)
    if (std::isdigit(*i)) out << *i;

strdate = out.str();
```

I make no promises about time or space complexity, but I suspect that using `string::erase` multiple times might involve a little more memory shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string strdate = "2012-06-25 05:32:06.963";
std::string result ="";
for(std::string::iterator itr = strdate.begin(); itr != strdate.end(); itr++)
{
    if(itr[0] >= '0' &&  itr[0] <= '9')
    {
        result.push_back(itr[0]);
    }
}
```