# How to use __DATE__ and __TIME__ predefined macros in as two integers, then stringify?

Tags: c, macros, predefined-macro

Want to use **__ DATE __ and __ TIME __** as integer for giving automated version to my code in compile time.

```
#define STRINGIZER(arg)     #arg
#define STR_VALUE(arg)      STRINGIZER(arg)

#define DATE_as_int_str useD(__DATE__) // What can be done ?
#define TIME_as_int_str useT(__TIME__) // What can be done ?

#define VERSION 1.4

#define COMPLETE_VERSION STR_VALUE(VERSION) "." DATE_as_int_str "." TIME_as_int_str
```

and get `COMPLETE_VERSION` as string in a `const unsigned char []`.

```
const unsigned char completeVersion[] = ?? COMPLETE_VERSION;
```

Should output **1.4.1432.2234** something.

One of the possible solution could be but did not work:  [convert-**date**-to-unsigned-int](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t316565-convert-__date__-to-unsigned-int.html)

In context of compile time  [convertint-date-and-time-string-to-just-integers-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204853/convertint-date-and-time-string-to-just-integers-in-c) 
One can refer  [expanssion-and-stringification-how-to-get-the-marco-name-not-its-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693219/macro-expanssion-and-stringification-how-to-get-the-marco-name-not-its-value/11694231#11694231)

Comment: Your `_VERSION` macro violates the identifier rule that starting with an underscore, followed by a capital letter is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @chris: I'll change the identifier. I'll put something else. another variable 'VERSION' is already there in my code so thinking what can be done.

Comment: As long as it doesn't then begin with two underscores, you should be fine.

Comment: Trying http://www.mail-archive.com/avr-gcc-list@nongnu.org/msg05718.html but not able to make it work.

Comment: I can stringify an integer macro easily but how to do it with which is already a string? Basically need to process it in parts of the string in compile time itself.

Comment: Every build automation tool has a way to auto-generate a version number.  You ought to mention which one you use.

Comment: Please go through the all reference links. I don't have that liberty. I am using a compiler which generates code for a chip as a hex file. Which I've to download in the chip as a program. Should I add this info in this question/

Comment: Seems I need to find out how chars are concatenated in compile time.  __TIME__[0] gives a char !!

Comment: Do you really need some sort of specific format like you have shown?  If you are doing hex for embedded, then tell your linker to make a special spot in memory that is big enough to hold the biggest format.  Then just place the following const char version[] = __DATE__##" "##__TIME__;  Then it will be up to the reader of this info to decipher it correctly.  Go to address 0xXX read Y bytes and voila you have your extra special date code. BTW, its all just bits, so you could choose to read it in hex if you wanted, at the end of the day its just a unique series of bits that identifies the build

Comment: I am currently going with the same as you have mentioned. But I need to have the format I've mentioned. If that can be done its better. Otherwise it'll be the same. :| Another will be a good knowledge to have here.

Comment: Your example string is: `1.4.1432.2234`  Could you please explain how `1432` is a date and `2234` is a time?  Is that time just `22:34`, (i.e. `10:34 P.M.`)?

Comment: Do you need this to be pure C, or can you compile with a C++ compiler?

Comment: I need it in C. I would like to learn, how it'll be done in C++. Please follow the links ( http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t316565-convert-__date__-to-unsigned-int.html ) for "date to integer" convertion.

Answer (score 77):

If you can use a C++ compiler to build the object file that you want to contain your version string, then we can do exactly what you want!  The only magic here is that C++ allows you to use expressions to statically initialize an array, while C doesn't.  The expressions need to be fully computable at compile time, but these expressions are, so it's no problem.

We build up the version string one byte at a time, and get exactly what we want.

```
// source file version_num.h

#ifndef VERSION_NUM_H

#define VERSION_NUM_H


#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 4


#endif // VERSION_NUM_H
```

---

```
// source file build_defs.h

#ifndef BUILD_DEFS_H

#define BUILD_DEFS_H


// Example of __DATE__ string: "Jul 27 2012"
//                              01234567890

#define BUILD_YEAR_CH0 (__DATE__[ 7])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH1 (__DATE__[ 8])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH2 (__DATE__[ 9])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH3 (__DATE__[10])


#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JAN (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_FEB (__DATE__[0] == 'F')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAR (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'r')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_APR (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'p')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAY (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'y')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUN (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUL (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'l')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_AUG (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'u')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_SEP (__DATE__[0] == 'S')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_OCT (__DATE__[0] == 'O')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_NOV (__DATE__[0] == 'N')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_DEC (__DATE__[0] == 'D')


#define BUILD_MONTH_CH0 \
    ((BUILD_MONTH_IS_OCT || BUILD_MONTH_IS_NOV || BUILD_MONTH_IS_DEC) ? '1' : '0')

#define BUILD_MONTH_CH1 \
    ( \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JAN) ? '1' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_FEB) ? '2' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAR) ? '3' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_APR) ? '4' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAY) ? '5' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUN) ? '6' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUL) ? '7' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_AUG) ? '8' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_SEP) ? '9' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_OCT) ? '0' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_NOV) ? '1' : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_DEC) ? '2' : \
        /* error default */    '?' \
    )

#define BUILD_DAY_CH0 ((__DATE__[4] >= '0') ? (__DATE__[4]) : '0')
#define BUILD_DAY_CH1 (__DATE__[ 5])



// Example of __TIME__ string: "21:06:19"
//                              01234567

#define BUILD_HOUR_CH0 (__TIME__[0])
#define BUILD_HOUR_CH1 (__TIME__[1])

#define BUILD_MIN_CH0 (__TIME__[3])
#define BUILD_MIN_CH1 (__TIME__[4])

#define BUILD_SEC_CH0 (__TIME__[6])
#define BUILD_SEC_CH1 (__TIME__[7])


#if VERSION_MAJOR > 100

#define VERSION_MAJOR_INIT \
    ((VERSION_MAJOR / 100) + '0'), \
    (((VERSION_MAJOR % 100) / 10) + '0'), \
    ((VERSION_MAJOR % 10) + '0')

#elif VERSION_MAJOR > 10

#define VERSION_MAJOR_INIT \
    ((VERSION_MAJOR / 10) + '0'), \
    ((VERSION_MAJOR % 10) + '0')

#else

#define VERSION_MAJOR_INIT \
    (VERSION_MAJOR + '0')

#endif

#if VERSION_MINOR > 100

#define VERSION_MINOR_INIT \
    ((VERSION_MINOR / 100) + '0'), \
    (((VERSION_MINOR % 100) / 10) + '0'), \
    ((VERSION_MINOR % 10) + '0')

#elif VERSION_MINOR > 10

#define VERSION_MINOR_INIT \
    ((VERSION_MINOR / 10) + '0'), \
    ((VERSION_MINOR % 10) + '0')

#else

#define VERSION_MINOR_INIT \
    (VERSION_MINOR + '0')

#endif



#endif // BUILD_DEFS_H
```

---

```
// source file main.c

#include "version_num.h"
#include "build_defs.h"

// want something like: 1.4.1432.2234

const unsigned char completeVersion[] =
{
    VERSION_MAJOR_INIT,
    '.',
    VERSION_MINOR_INIT,
    '-', 'V', '-',
    BUILD_YEAR_CH0, BUILD_YEAR_CH1, BUILD_YEAR_CH2, BUILD_YEAR_CH3,
    '-',
    BUILD_MONTH_CH0, BUILD_MONTH_CH1,
    '-',
    BUILD_DAY_CH0, BUILD_DAY_CH1,
    'T',
    BUILD_HOUR_CH0, BUILD_HOUR_CH1,
    ':',
    BUILD_MIN_CH0, BUILD_MIN_CH1,
    ':',
    BUILD_SEC_CH0, BUILD_SEC_CH1,
    '\0'
};


#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", completeVersion);
    // prints something similar to: 1.4-V-2013-05-09T15:34:49
}
```

This isn't exactly the format you asked for, but I still don't fully understand how you want days and hours mapped to an integer.  I think it's pretty clear how to make this produce any desired string.

Comment: Does processor expand all those macros - all the `if` statements and ternary operators. Or are they evaluated during compilation?

Comment: Evaluated during compilation, as long as the expression only uses constant data known at compile time as shown here.

Comment: is there version of this for C?

Comment: @Hasanalattar As explained in the first paragraph of the answer, the preprocessor in C does not allow the tricks that this answer needs; the preprocessor in C++ does allow the tricks.  However, the result of the above is that you can get the exact string you want in an object file, and you can link that to C code with no problem.  Linking _code_ from C++ with C code can be problematic but this is simple string data.  So you can have a whole project all in C, compiled with the C compiler, and just the one version string file compiled by the C++ compiler and it will link, no problem.

Comment: **BEWARE** that this only updates when the file containing it is recompiled.  Changing some other source file and re-linking the project will not cause the date to be updated, if you want that, you need a build system which either always does a full recompile, or has a special rule to always force the recompilation of the source file containing this.

Comment: **Side note**: In the Eclipse editor (at least on Win10), when hovering the ``__DATE__`` variable, the tooltip may show something like: "Nov. 24 2021", but when running the program, the string will actually be "Nov 24 2021" (so without the dot).
To **force recompiling** (and thus updating the date/time), delete the ".o" file of the file where the ``__DATE__`` is assigned, e.g. for Eclipse in Project Settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > Build Steps > Pre-build steps > Command - add (without quotes, adjust path):

``rm -f ${ProjDirPath}/Debug/Core/Src/version.o``

Comment: Appendix: It is even wilder than I thought. Today, when hovering the __DATE__, the tooltip will show "Aug. 03 2022", but the actual string used in the program is "Aug  3 2022" (two spaces between month and day when day < 10 although they are not shown here (so "Aug--3-2022")! no leading 0!).

Answer (score 20):

Here is a working version of the "build defs".  This is similar to my previous answer but I figured out the build month.  (You just can't compute build month in a `#if` statement, but you can use a ternary expression that will be compiled down to a constant.)

Also, according to the documentation, if the compiler cannot get the time of day it will give you question marks for these strings.  So I added tests for this case, and made the various macros return an obviously wrong value (99) if this happens.

```
#ifndef BUILD_DEFS_H

#define BUILD_DEFS_H


// Example of __DATE__ string: "Jul 27 2012"
// Example of __TIME__ string: "21:06:19"

#define COMPUTE_BUILD_YEAR \
    ( \
        (__DATE__[ 7] - '0') * 1000 + \
        (__DATE__[ 8] - '0') *  100 + \
        (__DATE__[ 9] - '0') *   10 + \
        (__DATE__[10] - '0') \
    )


#define COMPUTE_BUILD_DAY \
    ( \
        ((__DATE__[4] >= '0') ? (__DATE__[4] - '0') * 10 : 0) + \
        (__DATE__[5] - '0') \
    )


#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JAN (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_FEB (__DATE__[0] == 'F')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAR (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'r')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_APR (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'p')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAY (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'y')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUN (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUL (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'l')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_AUG (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'u')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_SEP (__DATE__[0] == 'S')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_OCT (__DATE__[0] == 'O')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_NOV (__DATE__[0] == 'N')
#define BUILD_MONTH_IS_DEC (__DATE__[0] == 'D')


#define COMPUTE_BUILD_MONTH \
    ( \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JAN) ?  1 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_FEB) ?  2 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAR) ?  3 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_APR) ?  4 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_MAY) ?  5 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUN) ?  6 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_JUL) ?  7 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_AUG) ?  8 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_SEP) ?  9 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_OCT) ? 10 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_NOV) ? 11 : \
        (BUILD_MONTH_IS_DEC) ? 12 : \
        /* error default */  99 \
    )

#define COMPUTE_BUILD_HOUR ((__TIME__[0] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[1] - '0')
#define COMPUTE_BUILD_MIN  ((__TIME__[3] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[4] - '0')
#define COMPUTE_BUILD_SEC  ((__TIME__[6] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[7] - '0')


#define BUILD_DATE_IS_BAD (__DATE__[0] == '?')

#define BUILD_YEAR  ((BUILD_DATE_IS_BAD) ? 99 : COMPUTE_BUILD_YEAR)
#define BUILD_MONTH ((BUILD_DATE_IS_BAD) ? 99 : COMPUTE_BUILD_MONTH)
#define BUILD_DAY   ((BUILD_DATE_IS_BAD) ? 99 : COMPUTE_BUILD_DAY)

#define BUILD_TIME_IS_BAD (__TIME__[0] == '?')

#define BUILD_HOUR  ((BUILD_TIME_IS_BAD) ? 99 :  COMPUTE_BUILD_HOUR)
#define BUILD_MIN   ((BUILD_TIME_IS_BAD) ? 99 :  COMPUTE_BUILD_MIN)
#define BUILD_SEC   ((BUILD_TIME_IS_BAD) ? 99 :  COMPUTE_BUILD_SEC)


#endif // BUILD_DEFS_H
```

With the following test code, the above works great:

```
printf("%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d\n", BUILD_YEAR, BUILD_MONTH, BUILD_DAY, BUILD_HOUR, BUILD_MIN, BUILD_SEC);
```

However, when I try to use those macros with your stringizing macro, it stringizes the literal expression!  I don't know of any way to get the compiler to reduce the expression to a literal integer value and then stringize.

Also, if you try to statically initialize an array of values using these macros, the compiler complains  with an `error: initializer element is not constant` message.  So you cannot do what you want with these macros.

At this point I'm thinking that your best bet is the Python script that just generates a new include file for you.  You can pre-compute anything you want in any format you want.  If you don't want Python we can write an AWK script or even a C program.

Answer (score 12):

I have a partial answer for you.  This is based on what I get from GCC:

`__DATE__` gives something like `"Jul 27 2012"`

`__TIME__` gives something like `21:06:19`

Put this text in an include file called `build_defs.h`:

```
#ifndef BUILD_DEFS_H

#define BUILD_DEFS_H


#define BUILD_YEAR ((__DATE__[7] - '0') * 1000 +  (__DATE__[8] - '0') * 100 + (__DATE__[9] - '0') * 10 + __DATE__[10] - '0')

#define BUILD_DATE ((__DATE__[4] - '0') * 10 + __DATE__[5] - '0')


#if 0
#if (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  1
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'F' && __DATE__[1] == 'e' && __DATE__[2] == 'b')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  2
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'r')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  3
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'p' && __DATE__[2] == 'r')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  4
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'M' && __DATE__[1] == 'a' && __DATE__[2] == 'y')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  5
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'n')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  6
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'J' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'l')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  7
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'A' && __DATE__[1] == 'u' && __DATE__[2] == 'g')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  8
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'S' && __DATE__[1] == 'e' && __DATE__[2] == 'p')
    #define BUILD_MONTH  9
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'O' && __DATE__[1] == 'c' && __DATE__[2] == 't')
    #define BUILD_MONTH 10
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'N' && __DATE__[1] == 'o' && __DATE__[2] == 'v')
    #define BUILD_MONTH 11
#elif (__DATE__[0] == 'D' && __DATE__[1] == 'e' && __DATE__[2] == 'c')
    #define BUILD_MONTH 12
#else
    #error "Could not figure out month"
#endif
#endif

#define BUILD_HOUR ((__TIME__[0] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[1] - '0')
#define BUILD_MIN ((__TIME__[3] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[4] - '0')
#define BUILD_SEC ((__TIME__[6] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__[7] - '0')

#endif // BUILD_DEFS_H
```

I tested the above with GCC on Linux.  It all works great, except for the problem that I can't figure out how to get a number for the month.  If you check the section that is under `#if 0` you will see my attempt to figure out the month.  GCC complains with this message:

```
error: token ""Jul 27 2012"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

It would be trivial to convert the three-letter month abbreviation into some sort of unique number; just subtract 'A' from the first letter and 'a' from the second and the third, and then convert to a base-26 number or something.  But I want to make it evaluate to 1 for January and so on, and I can't figure out how to do that.

EDIT: I just realized that you asked for strings, not expressions that evaluate to integer values.

I tried to use these tricks to build a static string:

```
#define BUILD_MAJOR 1
#define BUILD_MINOR 4
#define VERSION STRINGIZE(BUILD_MAJOR) "." STRINGIZE(BUILD_MINOR)

char build_str[] = {
    BUILD_MAJOR + '0', '.' BUILD_MINOR + '0', '.',
    __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10],
    '\0'
};
```

GCC complains that "initializer element is not constant" for `__DATE__`.

Sorry, I'm not sure how to help you.  Maybe you can try this stuff with your compiler?  Or maybe it will give you an idea.

Good luck.

P.S. If you don't need things to be numbers, and you just want a unique build string, it's easy:

```
const char *build_str = "Version: " VERSION " " __DATE__ " " __TIME__;
```

With GCC, this results in something like:

```
Version: 1.4 Jul 27 2012 21:53:59
```

Comment: I need to correctly stringify #define BUILD_HOUR (( __ TIME __ [0] - '0') * 10 + __TIME__ [1] - '0') . If I use const unsigned char df [] = BUILD_HOUR . It prints nothing or prints equivalent int. If I stringify that it gives prints (("10:24:33"[0] - '0') * 10 + "10:24:33"[1] - '0') . The thing is __ TIME __ is already a string.

Comment: I think will have to go with **Version: 1.4 Jul 27 2012 21:53:59** . But still looking if I get some more answers.

Comment: Seems no one wants to take challenge apart from u. I took it. :P

Comment: Just an idea to reduce the amount of tests in the `#if`. Some checks are suffisent to recognize a month, for instance: `__DATE__[0] == 'F'` in unambiguisly Feb or `__DATE__[2] == 'l'` is definitly Jul. This can reduce the number of checks and make it a bit less "heavy".

Comment: @tristopia -- I might change it to reduce the number of checks, *if* it actually worked.  Since it doesn't work, I left it as it was.

Answer (score 10):

You could always write a simple program in Python or something to create an include file that has simple `#define` statements with a build number, time, and date.  You would then need to run this program before doing a build.

If you like I'll write one and post source here.

If you are lucky, your build tool (IDE or whatever) might have the ability to run an external command, and then you could have the external tool rewrite the include file automatically with each build.

EDIT: Here's a Python program.  This writes a file called `build_num.h` and has an integer build number that starts at 1 and increments each time this program is run; it also writes `#define` values for the year, month, date, hours, minutes and seconds of the time this program is run.  It also has a `#define` for major and minor parts of the version number, plus the full `VERSION` and `COMPLETE_VERSION` that you wanted.  (I wasn't sure what you wanted for the date and time numbers, so I went for just concatenated digits from the date and time.  You can change this easily.)

Each time you run it, it reads in the `build_num.h` file, and parses it for the build number; if the `build_num.h` file does not exist, it starts the build number at 1.  Likewise it parses out major and minor version numbers, and if the file does not exist defaults those to version 0.1.

```
import time

FNAME = "build_num.h"

build_num = None
version_major = None
version_minor = None

DEF_BUILD_NUM = "#define BUILD_NUM "
DEF_VERSION_MAJOR = "#define VERSION_MAJOR "
DEF_VERSION_MINOR = "#define VERSION_MINOR "

def get_int(s_marker, line):
    _, _, s = line.partition(s_marker) # we want the part after the marker
    return int(s)

try:
    with open(FNAME) as f:
        for line in f:
            if DEF_BUILD_NUM in line:
                build_num = get_int(DEF_BUILD_NUM, line)
                build_num += 1
            elif DEF_VERSION_MAJOR in line:
                version_major = get_int(DEF_VERSION_MAJOR, line)
            elif DEF_VERSION_MINOR in line:
                version_minor = get_int(DEF_VERSION_MINOR, line)
except IOError:
    build_num = 1
    version_major = 0
    version_minor = 1

assert None not in (build_num, version_major, version_minor)


with open(FNAME, 'w') as f:
    f.write("#ifndef BUILD_NUM_H\n")
    f.write("#define BUILD_NUM_H\n")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(DEF_BUILD_NUM + "%d\n" % build_num)
    f.write("\n")
    t = time.localtime()
    f.write("#define BUILD_YEAR %d\n" % t.tm_year)
    f.write("#define BUILD_MONTH %d\n" % t.tm_mon)
    f.write("#define BUILD_DATE %d\n" % t.tm_mday)
    f.write("#define BUILD_HOUR %d\n" % t.tm_hour)
    f.write("#define BUILD_MIN %d\n" % t.tm_min)
    f.write("#define BUILD_SEC %d\n" % t.tm_sec)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("#define VERSION_MAJOR %d\n" % version_major)
    f.write("#define VERSION_MINOR %d\n" % version_minor)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("#define VERSION \"%d.%d\"\n" % (version_major, version_minor))
    s = "%d.%d.%04d%02d%02d.%02d%02d%02d" % (version_major, version_minor,
            t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec)
    f.write("#define COMPLETE_VERSION \"%s\"\n" % s)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("#endif // BUILD_NUM_H\n")
```

I made all the defines just be integers, but since they are simple integers you can use the standard stringizing tricks to build a string out of them if you like.  Also you can trivially extend it to build additional pre-defined strings.

This program should run fine under Python 2.6 or later, including any Python 3.x version.  You could run it under an old Python with a few changes, like not using `.partition()` to parse the string.

Comment: Yes, I've 'Build Actions' Post and Pre. Its a good idea. And acceptable for me. I can use any application to do that. I've gone with the simple date and time. Only thing is the 'Build Action' should be a blocking action. If thats so it a lottery. Thanks for the gr8 idea. This answer is worth vote up also. Should I select this answer as appropriate answer. Its a different kind of answer beyond the dimensions. Waiting for vote ups as response.

Comment: It's up to you to decide whether to accept an answer or not.  I think this question has had low views; not many people have even seen it, and I'm the only one so far to answer it.  So you might have to wait a while for the community to upvote my answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer (asked version): (format 3.33.20150710.182906)**

Please, simple use a `makefile` with:

```
MAJOR = 3
MINOR = 33
BUILD = $(shell date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")
VERSION = "\"$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(BUILD)\""
CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION=$(VERSION)

program.x : source.c
       gcc $(CPPFLAGS) source.c -o program.x
```

and if you don't want a `makefile`, shorter yet, just compile with:

```
gcc source.c -o program.x -DVERSION=\"2.22.$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")\"
```

---

**Short answer (suggested version): (format 150710.182906)**

Use a `double` for version number:

MakeFile:

```
VERSION = $(shell date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")
CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION=$(VERSION)
program.x : source.c
      gcc $(CPPFLAGS) source.c -o program.x
```

Or a simple bash command:

```
$ gcc source.c -o program.x -DVERSION=$(date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")
```

**Tip:**
Still don't like `makefile` or is it just for a not-so-small test program? Add this line:

```
 export CPPFLAGS='-DVERSION='$(date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")
```

to your `~/.profile`, and remember compile with `gcc $CPPFLAGS ...`

---

**Long answer:**

I know this question is older, but I have a small contribution to make. Best practice is always automatize what otherwise can became a source of error (or oblivion).

I was used to a function that created the version number for me. But I prefer this function to return a `float`. My version number can be printed by: `printf("%13.6f\n", version());` which issues something like: `150710.150411` (being Year (2 digits) month day DOT hour minute seconds).

But, well, the question is yours. If you prefer "major.minor.date.time", it will have to be a string. (Trust me, double is better. If you insist in a major, you can still use double if you set the major and let the decimals to be date+time, like: `major.datetime = 1.150710150411`

Lets get to business. The example bellow will work if you compile as usual, forgetting to set it, or use `-DVERSION` to set the version directly from shell, but better of all, I recommend the third option: use a `makefile`.

---

**Three forms of compiling and the results:**

**Using make:**

```
beco> make program.x
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors -c -DVERSION="\"3.33.20150710.045829\"" program.c -o program.o
gcc  program.o -o program.x
```

Running:

```
__DATE__: 'Jul 10 2015'
__TIME__: '04:58:29'
VERSION: '3.33.20150710.045829'
```

**Using -DVERSION:**

```
beco> gcc program.c -o program.x -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors -DVERSION=\"2.22.$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")\"
```

Running:

```
__DATE__: 'Jul 10 2015'
__TIME__: '04:58:37'
VERSION: '2.22.20150710.045837'
```

**Using the build-in function:**

```
beco> gcc program.c -o program.x -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors
```

Running:

```
__DATE__: 'Jul 10 2015'
__TIME__: '04:58:43'
VERSION(): '1.11.20150710.045843'
```

---

**Source code**

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <string.h>
  4 
  5 #define FUNC_VERSION (0)
  6 #ifndef VERSION
  7   #define MAJOR 1
  8   #define MINOR 11
  9   #define VERSION version()
 10   #undef FUNC_VERSION
 11   #define FUNC_VERSION (1)
 12   char sversion[]="9999.9999.20150710.045535";
 13 #endif
 14 
 15 #if(FUNC_VERSION)
 16 char *version(void);
 17 #endif
 18 
 19 int main(void)
 20 {
 21 
 22   printf("__DATE__: '%s'\n", __DATE__);
 23   printf("__TIME__: '%s'\n", __TIME__);
 24 
 25   printf("VERSION%s: '%s'\n", (FUNC_VERSION?"()":""), VERSION);
 26   return 0;
 27 }
 28 
 29 /* String format: */
 30 /* __DATE__="Oct  8 2013" */
 31 /*  __TIME__="00:13:39" */
 32
 33 /* Version Function: returns the version string */
 34 #if(FUNC_VERSION)
 35 char *version(void)
 36 {
 37   const char data[]=__DATE__;
 38   const char tempo[]=__TIME__;
 39   const char nomes[] = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
 40   char omes[4];
 41   int ano, mes, dia, hora, min, seg;
 42 
 43   if(strcmp(sversion,"9999.9999.20150710.045535"))
 44     return sversion;
 45 
 46   if(strlen(data)!=11||strlen(tempo)!=8)
 47     return NULL;
 48 
 49   sscanf(data, "%s %d %d", omes, &dia, &ano);
 50   sscanf(tempo, "%d:%d:%d", &hora, &min, &seg);
 51   mes=(strstr(nomes, omes)-nomes)/3+1;
 52   sprintf(sversion,"%d.%d.%04d%02d%02d.%02d%02d%02d", MAJOR, MINOR, ano, mes, dia, hora, min, seg);
 53 
 54   return sversion;
 55 }
 56 #endif
```

---

Please note that the string is limited by `MAJOR<=9999` and `MINOR<=9999`. Of course, I set this high value that will hopefully never overflow. But using `double` is still better (plus, it's completely automatic, no need to set `MAJOR` and `MINOR` by hand).

Now, the program above is a bit too much. Better is to remove the function completely, and guarantee that the macro `VERSION` is defined, either by `-DVERSION` directly into GCC command line (or an alias that automatically add it so you can't forget), or the recommended solution, to include this process into a `makefile`.

Here it is the `makefile` I use:

---

**MakeFile source:**

```
  1   MAJOR = 3
  2   MINOR = 33
  3   BUILD = $(shell date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")
  4   VERSION = "\"$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(BUILD)\""
  5   CC = gcc
  6   CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors
  7   CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION=$(VERSION)
  8   LDLIBS =
  9   
 10    %.x : %.c
 11          $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@
```

---

**A better version with DOUBLE**

Now that I presented you "your" preferred solution, here it is my solution:

**Compile with (a) makefile or (b) gcc directly:**

(a) MakeFile:

```
   VERSION = $(shell date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")
   CC = gcc
   CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors 
   CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION=$(VERSION)
   LDLIBS =
   %.x : %.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@
```

(b) Or a simple bash command:

```
 $ gcc program.c -o program.x -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic-errors -DVERSION=$(date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")
```

---

**Source code (double version):**

```
#ifndef VERSION
  #define VERSION version()
#endif

double version(void);

int main(void)
{
  printf("VERSION%s: '%13.6f'\n", (FUNC_VERSION?"()":""), VERSION);
  return 0;
}

double version(void)
{
  const char data[]=__DATE__;
  const char tempo[]=__TIME__;
  const char nomes[] = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
  char omes[4];
  int ano, mes, dia, hora, min, seg;
  char sversion[]="130910.001339";
  double fv;

  if(strlen(data)!=11||strlen(tempo)!=8)
    return -1.0;

  sscanf(data, "%s %d %d", omes, &dia, &ano);
  sscanf(tempo, "%d:%d:%d", &hora, &min, &seg);
  mes=(strstr(nomes, omes)-nomes)/3+1;
  sprintf(sversion,"%04d%02d%02d.%02d%02d%02d", ano, mes, dia, hora, min, seg);
  fv=atof(sversion);

  return fv;
}
```

Note: this double function is there only in case you forget to define macro VERSION. If you use a `makefile` or set an `alias gcc gcc -DVERSION=$(date +"%g%m%d.%H%M%S")`, you can safely delete this function completely.

---

Well, that's it. A very neat and easy way to setup your version control and never worry about it again!

Comment: never use a binary floating point variable when you wish exact decimal representation.

Comment: I see your point. There are ways to go around if some round occur. I'm using this format for a long time and have never had a problem. Besides, its easy to spot and almost its inoculum. I would agree in some more dangerous situation. Not here. Anyway, a simple workaroung is to include a little more zeros at the end, followed by a 5. `Version 1.1508122101150005`. That with the use of `double` instead of `float` would suffice. Just ignore numbers after the 12th decimal. It wont change the last one (the number relative of seconds in this case). Anyway, nice observation.

Comment: This is the only reasonable and foolproof answer here.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone just looking to replace the extra ' ' (space) if day is less than 10 then use:

```
#define BUILD_DATE (char const[]) { __DATE__[0], __DATE__[1], __DATE__[2], __DATE__[3], (__DATE__[4] == ' ' ?  '0' : __DATE__[4]), __DATE__[5], __DATE__[6], __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10], __DATE__[11] }
```

Output: Sep 06 2019

Answer (score -1):

it is very simple....

[in make file]

==== 1 ===================

OBJS = ....\

```
version.o <<== add to your obj lists
```

==== 2 ===================

DATE = $(shell date +'char szVersionStr[20] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";') <<== add

all:version $(ProgramID)  <<== version add at first

version:                  <<== add

```
echo '$(DATE)' > version.c  <== add ( create version.c file)
```

[in program]

=====3 =============

extern char szVersionStr[20];

[ using ]

=== 4 ====

```
printf( "Version: %s\n", szVersionStr );
```