# Xcode preprocessor macro for dates

Tags: xcode, datetime, macros

I want to "hardcode" an expiration date into my beta code. Right now I manually calculate a unix date and compare that to the current date time:

```
 if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]>1422748800) mustHalt = TRUE;
```

I'd like a way of replacing the `1422748800` with a macro that generates the equivalent number for a date 90 days in the future at compile time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predefined macro `__DATE__` is what you need. [Here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697820/how-to-use-date-and-time-predefined-macros-in-as-two-integers-then-stri) related to this. But maybe you want to use a code like this:

```
    const int daysToExpire = 14;

    NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [df setLocale:usLocale];
    NSDate *expireDate = [df dateFromString:compileDate];

    bool isExpired = ([[NSDate date] compare:expireDate] == NSOrderedDescending); // decide for it
```

Comment: A Macro is not needed and not even a hood idea, it would be better as just a method. The key part of the answer is using `__DATE__`. Additionally the code will not compile.

Comment: Sure, you are right. But as I understood, this was the question.

Comment: This works for me - thank you. The key was creating a compile-date-based constant.

Comment: @Zaph: Now I got you. But I think I got the intension.